# Insert data into static array

Tags: php

I want to create a table of available time slots which I can get with this:

```
echo "<table class='table table-sm'>
  <tr>
    <th>Time Slot</th>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>";
foreach(range(8,16) as $times){
  if(strlen($times) == 1){
    $times = '0'.$times;
  }
  $s = $times . ':00';
  $e = $times . ':30';
}
echo "<tr>
  <td>$s - $e</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to match services from by database in the time slot that matches and add the details for the appointment to display if the start time matches. I am unable to get it working, I either print the services I'm importing only (no extra time slots), just one service that matches the time, or the times duplicate for all services I try to import. I want something like this:

```
8:00 - 8:30
8:30 - 9:00
9:00 - 9:30 Name of service 452 John Doe
9:30 - 10:00
10:00 - 10:30
10:30 - 11:00
11:00 - 11:30 Name of service 453 Jane Doe
11:30 - 12:00 Name of service 454 Jean Doe
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you need to modify your code structure and logic. Currently, you are overwriting the `$s` and `$e` variables in each iteration of the `foreach` loop, so only the last time slot is being displayed in the table. Additionally, you need to fetch and match the services from your database within the loop. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
    echo "<table class='table table-sm'>
      <tr>
        <th>Time Slot</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>";
    
    foreach(range(8,16) as $hour) {
      $times = array();
      $s = sprintf("%02d:00", $hour);
      $e = sprintf("%02d:30", $hour);
      
      // Fetch services from the database that match the current time slot
      // Replace 'your_db_query' with your own code to retrieve the services
      $services = your_db_query($s, $e);
      
      // Display the time slot and services
      echo "<tr>
        <td>$s - $e</td>";
        
      if (empty($services)) {
        echo "<td colspan='4'>No service available</td>";
      } else {
        // Iterate over the services and display the details
        foreach ($services as $service) {
          $serviceName = $service['name']; // Replace 'name' with the appropriate column name from your database
          $serviceID = $service['id'];     // Replace 'id' with the appropriate column name from your database
          $customerName = $service['customer_name']; // Replace 'customer_name' with the appropriate column name from your database
          
          echo "<td>$serviceName</td>
            <td>$serviceID</td>
            <td>$customerName</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>";
        }
      }
    }
    
    echo "</table>";
```

In this code, I've made a few changes:

1. I used `sprintf()` to format the time strings as `hh:mm` with leading zeros for single-digit hours.
2. I added a placeholder function `your_db_query()` to represent your actual database query code. You need to replace it with your own implementation to fetch services from the database within the given time range.
3. I introduced an inner loop to iterate over the retrieved services and display their details in separate table cells.

Make sure to replace the column names (`name`, `id`, `customer_name`) in the inner loop with the appropriate column names from your database schema.

This updated code should display the desired table with time slots and match the services to the corresponding time slots, showing the service details accordingly.

Based on the provided code, let's assume we have the following sample output for the table:

```
<table class='table table-sm'>
  <tr>
    <th>Time Slot</th>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08:00 - 08:30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08:30 - 09:00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09:00 - 09:30</td>
    <td>Name of service 452</td>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09:30 - 10:00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10:00 - 10:30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10:30 - 11:00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:00 - 11:30</td>
    <td>Name of service 453</td>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:30 - 12:00</td>
    <td>Name of service 454</td>
    <td>Jean Doe</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- More time slots can be added here -->
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't see it even after breaking it down a few times. That did the trick.